# NGINX Ingress controller, SSL and optional_no_ca

Tags: nginx, ssl, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have obtained a cert from name.com.

```sh
➜ tree .     
.
├── ca.crt
├── vpk.crt
├── vpk.csr
└── vpk.key
```

**How I created the secrets**

I added ca.crt content at the end of vpk.crt file.

```sh
(⎈ | vpk-dev-eks:argocd)
➜ k create secret tls tls-secret --cert=vpk.crt --key=vpk.key --dry-run -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -

(⎈ | vpk-dev-eks:argocd)
➜ kubectl create secret generic ca-secret --from-file=ca.crt=ca.crt --dry-run -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

**This is my ingress:**

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: websockets-ingress
  namespace: development
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "3600"
    # Enable client certificate authentication
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: "optional_no_ca"
    # Create the secret containing the trusted ca certificates
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: "development/ca-secret"
    # Specify the verification depth in the client certificates chain
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-depth: "1"
    # Specify if certificates are passed to upstream server
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-pass-certificate-to-upstream: "true"
    argocd.argoproj.io/sync-wave: "10"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - backend-dev.project.com
      secretName: tls-secret
  
  rules:
  - host: backend-dev.project.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /ws/
        backend:
          serviceName: websockets-service
          servicePort: 443
```

The cert is properly validated, I can connect via various CLI WebSocket clients and https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest gives me "A+"

However if I set

`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: "on"`

then everything stops working and I get 400 error on the nginx ingress controller side (POD logs).

**I am confused from the official docs:**

The optional_no_ca parameter (1.3.8, 1.2.5) requests the client certificate but does not require it to be signed by a trusted CA certificate. This is intended for the use in cases when a service that is external to nginx performs the actual certificate verification. The contents of the certificate is accessible through the $ssl_client_cert variable.

#### So what exactly "optional_no_ca" is doing and why "on" fails the requests?

Comment: Do you use Cloudflare? Could you try with `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: "ca-secret"` instead of  `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: "development/ca-secret"`? There is related [github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/pull/2390) about that.  I'm a bit confused about the auth-tls-verify-client, you used `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: "yes"`, which I think should be `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: "on"`, as there is no `yes` value in auth-tls-verify-client, could you try change that and test again?

Comment: @Jakub - sorry I used the option "on", not ~yes~. So with "on", I was getting 400 error. So my question is to understand what specifically happens behind the scene when we set "optional_no_ca"?

Comment: According to [documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/),  it does optional client certificate validation, but do not fail the request when the client certificate is not signed by the CAs from auth-tls-secret. So if with `auth-tls-verify-client: "on"` you get 400 then I assume there is an issue with `auth-tls-secret`. Have you tried to change it to `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: "ca-secret"` with `auth-tls-verify-client: "on"` as I mentioned above?

Comment: @DmitrySemenov Hello, are you still affected by this issue? Have you managed to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Optional_no_ca** does the optional client certificate validation and it does not fail the request when the client certificate is not signed by the CAs from **auth-tls-secret**. Even after specifying the optional_no_ca parameter, it is necessary to provide the client certificate. As mentioned in the document [1](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_trusted_certificate), the actual certificate verification is done when the service is external to Nginx.

When you set **nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client:on**,
it requests a client certificate that must be signed by a certificate that is included in the secret key **ca.crt** of the secret specified by **nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: secretName**.

If not so, then certificate verification will fail and result in a status code 400 (Bad Request). Check [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#client-certificate-authentication) for further information.