# Nginx controller Client Authentication optional_no_ca not working

Tags: nginx, github, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, configmap

We are using Kubernetes and we need to check the client cert. What we need is to configure the Nginx ingress controller in order to pass the client certificate (if present) to the back-end service.
We successfully configured it in our test environment. Here we have the following version:

- Container runtimedocker://19.3.8
- Kubelet version v1.17.6
- nging 1.17

We used this ingress configuration:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: login-cns-produzione-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: "proxy_set_header X-SSL-CERT $ssl_client_escaped_cert;"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: "ssl_verify_client optional_no_ca ;"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - login-cns.it
  rules:
  - host: login-cns.it
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: login-cns-produzione-service
          servicePort: 443
```

In our production environment, something is newer than the test.
These are the versions in production:

- Container runtimedocker://19.3.15
- Kubelet versionv1.18.15
- nging 1.19

The issue in production is that although we specify the directive `optional_no_ca` the ingress controller asks for the client certificate and tries to validate it and it fails
Do you have any idea about why this happens?

Thank you

Angelo

**EDIT**

By reading [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#client-certificate-authentication) it seems I should use these annotations. But by adding them, the client certificate is not asked by Nginx

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: login-cns-test-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "3600"
    # Enable client certificate authentication
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: "optional_no_ca"
    # Create the secret containing the trusted ca certificates
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: "wso2is-collaudo/iamcoll-it"
    # Specify the verification depth in the client certificates chain
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-depth: "1"
    # Specify if certificates are passed to upstream server
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-pass-certificate-to-upstream: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-error-page: "/cns/saml/dettagli-utente"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - login-cns-test.it
  rules:
  - host: login-cns-test.it
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: login-cns-test-service
          servicePort: 443
```

The very strange thing is that with the previous annotation, I have some X.509 authentications successful and others unsuccessful. I really can't explain the issue.

More info about the versions:

- nginx ingress controller version:
  nginx-ingress-controller:nginx-0.35.0-rancher2
- nginx version: 1.19.2
- openss version: OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020

Any tips would be very appreciated... I'm fighting on this issue for several days

**EDIT 2**

If I use this configuration:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: login-cns-test-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
                        proxy_set_header X-SSL-CERT $ssl_client_escaped_cert;
                        error_page 495 496 497 ​/cns/saml/dettagli-utente;
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
                         ssl_verify_client optional_no_ca;
                         if ($ssl_client_verify != SUCCESS) {
                              return 495;
                          }
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - login-cns-test.it
  rules:
  - host: login-cns-test.it
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: login-cns-test-service
          servicePort: 443
```

The client certificate is asked but, then, Nginx fails on certificate verification and it stops... It doesn't allow the request to be routed to the default backend where I have all the business logic to check and verify the certificate

**EDIT 3**

In my nginx ingress controller logs I see:

```
2021/06/14 19:17:29 [crit] 9793#9793: *89059516 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0407E068:rsa routines:RSA_verify_PKCS1_PSS_mgf1:bad signature error:1417B07B:SSL routines:tls_process_cert_verify:bad signature) while SSL handshaking, client: XXX.YY.ZZ.WW, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

So far, so good... I want that my Java application checks the certificate. But all the flow stops here. It seems I can't correctly configure the Nginx ingress controller `error_page` directive. Maybe should I configure the Nginx ingress controller ConfigMap (https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap.md#custom-http-errors)?

Answer (score 2):

Even after specifying the `optional_no_ca` parameter, it is *necessary* to provide the client certificate and because of using this parameter, it is not mandatory that the certificate is signed by the trusted CA [1](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_verify_client) [2](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/338).

Comment: Thank you for the answer but... why in the other environment doesn't this happen? Maybe a previous nginx version doesn't check the certificate?

Comment: It is not seems to be caused by NGINX version but may be associated with auth-tls-verify-client:ON key and could you please refer the below post to see whether it helps.                                         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64997718/nginx-ingress-controller-ssl-and-optional-no-ca

Comment: I updated my question.... Please give a look there if you can... thank you